# How to align a set of my equations?

Tags: equations, align

I just wan't to align the equation like this example (Of course, I can't align these equations on the web page):

```
∵△ABC ≌ △A′B′C′
∴∠ABC = ∠A′B′C′
  ∠ACB = ∠A′C′B′
  ∠BAC = ∠B′A′C′
```

If I use `&`, these will be to much spaces...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**

You can use a space `\,` or use `alignat` as told by **Gonzalo Medina**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %% provides amsmath with additional features and bug fixes
\usepackage{amssymb}   %% provides symbols like \because and \therefore

\begin{document}
Using \verb|align|

\begin{align*}
    \because \triangle \mathrm{ABC}   &= \triangle \mathrm{A^{'}B^{'}C^{'}}   \\
    \therefore\, \angle \mathrm{ABC}  &= \angle  \mathrm{A^{'}B^{'}C^{'}}     \\
    \angle \mathrm{ACB}               &= \angle \mathrm{A^{'}C^{'}B^{'}}      \\
    \angle \mathrm{BAC}               &= \angle \mathrm{B^{'}A^{'}C^{'} }
\end{align*}

Using \verb|alignat|
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\because   &\triangle \mathrm{ABC} &= \triangle \mathrm{A^{'}B^{'}C^{'}}   \\
&\therefore &\angle \mathrm{ABC}    &= \angle \mathrm{A^{'}B^{'}C^{'}}      \\
&           &\angle \mathrm{ACB}    &= \angle \mathrm{A^{'}C^{'}B^{'}}      \\
&           &\angle \mathrm{BAC}    &= \angle \mathrm{B^{'}A^{'}C^{'} }
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I also need to ailgn \because and \therefore.

Comment: @HarishKumar you're probably right in this case, but for other situations it's handy to know about `alignat` ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Agreed, my thoughts too. Hence added it in the answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Another option will be to use falignat, which will force e therefore and because to the left of the display.